# Fetched timestamp field via MySQL Connector/J 8.0.23 is incorrect

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-5.7

In the data source URL we include `serverTimezone=UTC`, and the server is also running in UTC. We were using version `6.0.6` of the connector and had no issues with `TIMESTAMP` fields coming back just as they went into the database. However, upgrading to version `8.0.23` causes the `TIMESTAMP` field to be incorrect;

```
Expected :2018-09-18T00:00:00Z
Actual   :2018-09-17T04:00:00Z
```

This is after a round-trip to/from the database (MySQL 5.7), and note that the field in the database is `TIMESTAMP`, and on the Java side it is `Instant`.

I tested this with a bunch of different 8.x versions of MySQL Connector/J and found that it was working in all that I tested except for the latest, `8.0.23`.

Viewing the release notes for this version, they call out some changes to timezone handling:

[image: release notes]

Strange that a patch version would introduce such a change! However, they state that the way we are connecting should result in the same behavior as before (though it does not):

> Users who had serverTimeZone=user-defined-time-zone and keep it the same, without configuring the new connection properties, can expect the same behavior as before, but testing is recommended.

I've tried updating the connection string with a variety of options e.g. `connectionTimeZone=UTC`, `forceConnectionTimeZoneToSession=true`, `preserveInstants=true` -- but nothing seems to work for this version.

Am I missing something here, or does this seem like a bug? FWIW, [no bug is listed](https://bugs.mysql.com/search.php?search_for=&bug_type%5B%5D=Connector%2FJ&status%5B%5D=Active&severity=all&limit=30&order_by=&cmd=display&phpver=8.0.23&os=0&os_details=&bug_age=0&cpu_arch=0&cpu_arch_details=&last_updated=0&tags=&similar=)  which covers this.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is an ill conceived data type. It represents a timestamp in the server time zone. If the server time zone changes, or you backup/restore to a different server, MySQL may corrupt the data. In addition to this, `TIMESTAMP` it will run out of values in 2038. Try using `DATETIME` whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will add that to the list of things we should fix! :)

Comment: Yes, there has been a large refactoring in the temporal types handling in version 8.0.23. Please file a bug providing as many details as possible and a complete test case. The information you provide here is just not enough to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also check https://insidemysql.com/support-for-date-time-types-in-connector-j-8-0/ for more details.

For migration from c/J 6.0.6 it should be enough to additionally set preserveInstants=true. But the question is how do you store and retrieve the Instant, Connector/J does not have a built-in support for that. Connector/J 8.0.23 preserves instant values only in certain cases, please check "Preserving instants" chapter, probably you need to use a different getter.

Comment: the article referred to in the link is blank

Comment: It's moved to https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/support-for-date-time-types-in-connector-j-8-0/